# How do I change SQL query output?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using this simple SQL query to retrieve data from two tables in my MySQL database:

```
SELECT customer_id, domain_name
FROM customers_orders
INNER JOIN orders ON order_id = sub_id
```

The result is similar to this:

```
1114    somedomain.com
1115    anotherdomain.net
1116    domain1.org
1116    domain2.com
```

How do I tell it to give me an output that is rather similar to:

```
1114    somedomain.com
1115    anotherdomain.net
1116    domain1.org, domain2.com
```

So as to avoid having two lines with the same customer_id... I wonder if it is even possible with SQL? I'm a beginner in SQL and I would very much appreciate your help on this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: user aggregate functions, maybe called String aggregate functions.  STRAGG in oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try somethin like this

```
SELECT customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(domain_name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM customers_orders
INNER JOIN orders ON order_id = sub_id
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: +1 for group_concat :) although I don't think it is a good practice to use it, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
SELECT customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(domain_name ORDER BY domain_name SEPARATOR ', ') domain_name
FROM customers_orders INNER JOIN orders 
ON order_id = sub_id
GROUP BY customers_orders.customer_id
```

Answer (score 3):

Try next:

```
select customer_id, group_concat(domain_name separator ', ')
    from customers_orders group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No, it isn't</strike>. It is possible via `GROUP_CONCAT`, as suggested by others. But I wouldn't advise to use it. It is better to handle this in your processing code. It will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: It's definitely possbile somehow. If you google "sql+group by concat", then you find different solutions.